# Python code using Fabric does not use remote hosts

Tags: python, fabric

I am using python 3.6 with Fabric3 1.13.1 . Following is a simplified version of the code that I am using.

```
from fabric.api import *
from file import func 

env.hosts = ['user@myserver:22' ]
env.passwords={'user@myserver:22':'password'}

def test():

    func() # function defined in func
```

This code is saved in the file named fabfile.py. When I run  `fab test` in the terminal, execution starts as

> ['user@myserver:22' ] Executing task 'test'

But the resources at *localhost* are being used instead of at *myserver*, according to htop. And no processes are being started at *myserver*.

Does Fabric revert to localhost silently if it cannot find *myserver* ?

*EDIT*
I also tried

```
execute(func(), hosts = ['myserver'])
```

in a separate python file, as well as in fabfile, both of these ways excecute on *localhost* !

*EDIT 2*
The only thing that seems to run on the remote host is 
`run("commands_to_run")` # This picks the host from the list env.hosts

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `run()` to execute shell commands on the remote host.

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run

For example:

```
def test():
    local("hostname")
    run("hostname")

    another_function()
```

This will run the `hostname` shell command on both the local computer and remote host.

Fabric does not support executing arbitrary Python functions on a remote host. `another_function()` will always run on the local computer.

Comment: So what would I have to do in order to run it on a remote host? Do I  have to run(" ssh myserver") first ?

Comment: No. Just call run("command") where "command" is what you want to run on the remote server. Fabric will take care of logging in and running it. If you want to run a python file on the remote server you would do run("python /path/to/file.py") where file.py is located on the remote server.

Comment: Thanks. That works, I already tried that ( after your suggestion) . I wanted to execute a python function remotely and I thought execute( ) function would let me do that but that didn't work either. Is there a way to   use run( ) on a specific host without changing the env.hosts list or making a new function ( using decorator to set the host) ?

Comment: @Junaid see my posted answer regarding the use of execute.

Answer (score 1):

According to your Edit1, you are not using `execute` correctly.

The first argument in execute should be calling run. The difference is that the hosts will be picked up from second argument rather than `env.hosts`.

```
def func():
    run( "commands_to_run" )


execute(func, hosts = ['myserver'])
```